# Nlog logger object gets disposed when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

We're using NLog for our application. I have set up the logger in the code using mostly the documentation. Yet the logger object gets disposed of while the app is about to write to it causing an error. I use the logger in .NET CORE 3.1 in the Middlewares that handles exceptions globally and authentication. The funniest part is that the error itself is logged to the file by NLog.  Error from the logs:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'LoggerFactory'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1..ctor(ILoggerFactory factory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactoryExtensions.CreateLogger[T](ILoggerFactory factory)
```

Configuration in the code:

```
 public static class NLogConfig
 {
        public static void CreateLogger(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var logName = configuration.GetSection("LoggerConfig").GetSection("LogName").Get<string>();
            var logPath = configuration.GetSection("LoggerConfig").GetSection("Directory").Get<string>();
            var infoLogLayout = configuration.GetSection("LoggerConfig").GetSection("InfoLayout").Get<string>();
            var errorLogLayout = configuration.GetSection("LoggerConfig").GetSection("ErrorLayout").Get<string>();

            var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
            var infoLog = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("FileLog") { FileName = logPath + logName, Layout = infoLogLayout };
            var errorLog = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("FileLog") { FileName = logPath + logName, Layout = errorLogLayout };
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Info, infoLog);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Warn, LogLevel.Fatal, errorLog);
            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
        }
}
```

JSON configuration file:

```
"LoggerConfig": {
    "LogName": "MY_API_${shortdate}.log",
    "Directory": "C:\\Logs\\MY_API\\",
    "InfoLayout": "${longdate} | INFO  | ${logger} | ${message}",
    "ErrorLayout": "------------------\n${longdate} | ERROR | ${logger} | ${message:withexception=true} \n------------------"
  }
```

In the classes that use the log I do this as it is in documentation:

```
private static readonly NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

The "disposed" error happens randomly and not frequently, but often enough to be a slight concern. How can I avoid this problem? I've read that NLog should be thread-safe so calls to the API shouldn't cause such a problem. Especially when it was only one person using the API at the time

Comment: In your code, do you use NLog API or Microsoft Logging Abstraction (`ILogger<T>`) ? How do you register all this to Dependency Injection?

Comment: @Fildor The only additional thing I have for the configuration of NLog is this line of code: NLogConfig.CreateLogger(Configuration); written in Configure method of Startup.cs file before Use Middleware,Routing and Endpoints

Comment: It looks like it might be your `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory` (or possibly the `string CategoryName` parameter) that has been disposed, and nothing to do with NLog at all.

Comment: @TimLong the Logger Factory is being used by NLog automatically. In my configuration, I don't really have any control over that.

Comment: @T4under4 NLog doesn't use `LoggerFactory` or `LoggerFactory.CreateLogger` for doing logging. Those are infrastructure for Microsoft Extensions Lgging, and it seems you have disposed them, but continue to use them.

Comment: @RolfKristensen I have honestly no idea how is this possible. The project is currently pretty small and I even searched for any usage of this library and it's not declared anywhere at all. I only use NLog libraries for configuration and creating a logger object. What I found however is that I had Microsoft DLLs on the deployment server (I think it was there due to Nlog.Extensions.Logging nuget package that was in the project, but not used anywhere). I removed that nuget package and will attempt to deploy again. Hopefully that's the reason behind the problem